# Label Mapping image to corresponding name by using a dictionary

Tags: python, image, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset with flower images called `train_data`. I also have a dictionary called `class_names` with the integer coded labels to the actual names of the flowers. For extra clarity here is a sample of how the `class_names` dictionary outputs:

```
Output: 
{'21': 'fire lily',
'3': 'canterbury bells',
'45': 'bolero deep blue',
 '1': 'pink primrose',
'34': 'mexican aster'}
```

The objective is to Plot one image from the training set. Set the title of the plot to the corresponding class name. For example, if a flower is outputted it should take that of its label and it's class name. 
The code does not output an error and does plot the label of the image. However, it does not plot the class name correctly. Rather it sets the name to None. As seen in the image below:

[image]

Assistance would be appreciated to get the label and name of the respectful image. Here is my code below:

```
for image, label in train_data.take(1):
image = image.numpy().squeeze()
label = label.numpy()
plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.title(class_names.get(label))
# Display image
plt.show()
print('The label of this image is:', label)
print('The class name of this image is:', class_names.get(label))
```

Comment: could you try printing `label` once. is it giving intezer or string number?

Comment: it is a key error so i am wondering if I am iterating properly?

Answer (score 1):

could you try printing `label` once. is it giving intezer or string number? Because ur dictionary keys are strings. and if a key is not present in the dictionary, the get method returns None and no error

```
>>> a = {1:'a'}
>>> a.get(1)
'a'
>>> a.get(2)
>>> a[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 2
>>>
```